# How to make sure UI updates before continuing

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm new to JavaFX, and I have a button which initiates and object and does some methods with it. The problem is that the UI doesn't update until after the object performs the methods. When I click the button, the GUI doesn't respond (it says "(Not responding)" in the title bar. After the methods are finished, the UI updates. The only way I could see fixing this is waiting for the UI to update and then perform the methods. Is there any other way? How do I fix this?

```
Object myObj;
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                /* some ui updates */
                myLabel.setText("something");
            try {
                 /* try initiating object and doing some methods with them */
                 myObj = new Object();
                 myObj.doMethod();
```

Comment: Your `doMethod()` method consumes a lot of time, right? This is not a javafx problem, it's a problem of single threaded applications. You need to create a new thread and don't use the main thread from the gui.

Comment: @JoshuaK it takes four to five seconds max. I call the methods to change the UI before, so it should update the UI before, and then continue.

Comment: the `handle` method works in the same thread. so the update will be performed, when the `handle` method is finished. If your doMethod-method takes four or five seconds, the gui is updatet after these time... normal behavior.

Comment: @JoshuaK Oh, ok. I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new thread for the time consuming method:
(I'm also rewriting your code with lambda expressions... Java8 style ;))

```
Object myObj;
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{
    /* some ui updates */
    myLabel.setText("something");
    try {
        /* try initiating object and doing some methods with them */
        Runnable timeConsumingTask = ()-> {
            myObj = new Object();
            myObj.doMethod();
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(timeConsumingTask);
        thread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was creating a whole new class entirely thanks!